# What to do in Andorra during the summer?

Tags: culture, activities, summer, pyrenees, andorra

I have the opportunity to visit **Andorra** in the summer (La Cortinada). The Pyrenees look beautiful, but I wonder what else is there to do except for shopping and hiking - although a (secret!) **Holy Grail trek** would be an interesting proposal...:) That aside, are there any lakes/rivers to **swim** in, also what about a bit of **culture** for a rainy day, too.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind driving some kilometers to Spain, visit the beautiful town of [La Seu d'Urgell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Seu_d%27Urgell).

And if you like playing in water, you must try [Caldea](http://www.caldea.com/).

[image]
[image]
[image]

(Pictures from the web site)